# Convert the integer numeric numbers into percentages

Tags: r

In an input data structure

```
data.frame(stockname = c("google", "amazon"), open= c(30, 40), close = c(32, 48))
```

How is it possible to convert the interger number which is existed in every row with the respectively percentage using as sum the full sum of all rows of the data frame to calculate the percentage.

The total sum of all rows of the input data is 150 so the percentage example output data frame is

```
data.frame(stockname = c("google", "amazon"), open= c(20%, 26.7%), close = c(21.3%, 32%))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using `prop.table`:

```
df[-1] <- prop.table(df[-1])
df
#   stockname      open     close
# 1    google 0.2000000 0.2133333
# 2    amazon 0.2666667 0.3200000
```

If you're interested in formatting the output as well, look at `sprintf`. Starting with the source data again, try:

```
df[-1] <- sprintf("%.1f%%", unlist(prop.table(df[-1])) * 100)
df
#   stockname  open close
# 1    google 20.0% 21.3%
# 2    amazon 26.7% 32.0%
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you are after

```
df[-1] <- df[-1] / sum(df[-1])
```

which gives

```
> df
  stockname      open     close
1    google 0.2000000 0.2133333
2    amazon 0.2666667 0.3200000
```